# wp-cli is hitting a 120 second max execution time

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to run phpcompat using wp-cli, but it keeps hitting a 120 second max execution time. The docs for phpcompat state that wp-cli has no execution time limit, and I can't figure out where this is coming from. I thought it might be something in my server setup, so I set up a new server using the wordpress docker images, and the problem still exists.

How do I remove this time limit from wp-cli? I'm using `wp phpcompat 7.3` as the scan command.